# Change CSS style on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to change some of css style properties on div element when I click button, but I don't have that much experience nor I can find anything online to help me.
At the present moment this is how my code looks like.

```
<button class="button1">Click</button>
<div class="popup_middle">
</div>
<div class="grayout">
</div>
```

and my CSS looks like this

```
.grayout {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #000;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 55);
    opacity:.80;
}

.popup_middle{
    position: fixed;
    background: url(../images/bg-food-order.jpg);
    border: none;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 350px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-top: -125px;
    margin-left: -175px;
    z-index: 100;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Please could you pleas give me some advice or code sample with JS that is going to solve my problem.

Thanks in Advance ,
David

Comment: Have you tried to do this yourself? Can we see that JS code? You used the jQuery tag but I cant tell if you are using it or not

Comment: You could add a class on click and give in that class the needed css properites

Comment: all I have is this piece of button <button onClick="document.getElementById('popup_middle').style.visibility='visible'">Click</button>

Answer (score 4):

Something like

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$('.button1').click(function() { $('.popup_middle').hide().css('color', 'blue'); });

</script>
```

Would hide that popup_middle div and set the text color to blue when you clicked on the button. click() is the event handler

Comment: Why don't you using `.hide()` method instead?

Comment: ha this is wrong anyway. i'll edit it (display none is a style)

Answer (score 1):

so if you want to add css class style to a text using a button:=>

```
          <script>
            function changed(){
            document.getElementById("exp").classList.add("the class style name")};
          </Script>
              <div id="exp">
                <button onclick=" changed()">try it</button>
                <p onclick="changed()">hello world</p>

              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `getElementById` which will look for elements with an id. The div you are looking for has a **class** but no id. So when you run the code you have, nothing happens because the javascript cant find any element with an **id** of `popup_middle`.

To fix this you can change the `div` to have an **Id** of `popup_middle` and your CSS should have  `#popup_middle`.

HTML:

```
<button onClick="document.getElementById('popup_middle').style.visibility='visible';">Cli‌ck</button>
<div id="popup_middle"></div>
<div class="grayout"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.grayout {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=55);
    opacity:.80;
}
#popup_middle {
    position: fixed;
    background: green;
    border: none;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 350px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-top: -125px;
    margin-left: -175px;
    z-index: 100;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eLJYZ/2/